# PHP - value from variable to constant

Tags: php, oop, variables, constants

I'm learning OOP in PHP and I want to put value from variable to class constant. How can I do that?

This is my code (not working!):

```
class Dir {

const ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."project/";

function __construct() {

}
}
```

Is there any solution, how to take value from variable, add string and put it to constant - in OOP?

Comment: 1: What error are you getting. 2: What have you tried 3: why define your constant on a class level, while clearly it's a constant that belongs on a global level 3: Try changing root to `PROJECT_ROOT`, as `ROOT` is a dangerous constant to define (too close to environment variables, if you ask me)

Comment: On a note, using global constants in classes is not recommended. What happens when you want to reuse your classes but don't require any of the constants in a global scope? Use Getters and Setters instead for this kind of data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the manual page http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php you can find that:

```
The value must be a constant expression, not (for example) a variable, a property, a result of a mathematical operation, or a function call.
```

Comment: +1 - instead of using a class constant the OP could use a static property: `static $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."project/"`

Comment: yes, that might be an option but you can find here http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php that "A property declared as static can not be accessed with an instantiated class object".. maybe a config file (that can be a class) where this value is defined.. that can be just defined as a string and changed on each server (like any config value) to avoid depending on the $_SERVER superglobal..

Comment: that jsut means it cant be accessed like `$instance->root` instead you have to ALWAYS do `TheClassName::$root` but you can definitely access and change that value from an instance - you jsut need to use static notation.

Comment: The idea that you can't assign a constant with the value of a variable is idiotic. If that's how PHP was set up, then the committee who wrote that standard are incompetent in certain fundamental computer science concepts.

The intention of a constant is to keep programmers from accidentally altering its value the way they might a variable. It's NOT to prevent anything variable from being used to create that constant in the first place.

You can easily be attempting to grab a value from a variable and lock it into an unchanging constant. That is entirely valid according to the CS premise.

Answer (score 2):

Constant can't have variables.

I suggest you not to depend on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, instead, you could define the `ROOT` your self.

For example, you have a `config.php` in the document root, you could do

```
define('ROOT', __DIR__.'/'); // php version >= 5.3
define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__).'/'); // php version < 5.3
```

then use the `ROOT` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why not set it in your `__construct()`. Technically, that's what it is there for.

```
class Dir {

    public function __construct() {
        self::ROOT = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."project/";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you this solution because you want to use OOP and all have to be inside the class. So because a const or static var direct use is not possible I would use a static function:

```
class Dir
{
    public static function getRoot()
    {
        return $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'project/';
    }
}
```

and you can use it like

```
Dir::getRoot();
```