# Assign variable value to a constant

Tags: php, variables, constants

A PHP constant is defined like this:

```
define('const_name','const_value');
```

Tried like this:

```
define('const_name', $variable_name);
```

Why? because I'm a beginner and I figured if this works:

```
define('const_name', 50);
```

my version will work also. It doesn't. Should it work and it doesn't because I mistyped something, or my attempt is just plain stupid?

Note: Inside my variable is a Google Analytics ID extracted from a mysql DB. Just a string like this UA-XXXXX-Y, nothing more.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* [doesn't explain the problem](http://stuck.include-once.org/#help3) enough. You need to elaborate on your input, expected and actual outcomes, or concretise error messages.

Comment: What you're doing should work, so yes, either you mistyped something or the contents of your variable are not what you think they are. If you're not getting an error message, make sure you have error reporting turned on.

Comment: @mario. I have a condition which says that if that constant is defined echo the google tracking code with the ID, else don't show the tracking code entirely. But the ID is inside the DB so i'm not extracting it correctly. I'm doing smth wrong and I just wanted to know if this is it.

Comment: Asked several times already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396920/php-value-from-variable-to-constant?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481869/change-the-value-of-a-previously-defined-constant?rq=1

Comment: `" Inside my variable is a Google Analytics ID extracted from a mysql DB"`. in that case it is a variable, not a constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$myVariable="what up";
define('myConstant',"$myVariable");
echo myConstant;
```

Really though, why define a variable as a constant? This is not a good habit to get into.

Comment: I have smth like this $info['google_id'] coming from the DB and I need to put it inside a constant. Can I do this: define('const_name', '$info['google_id']')?

Comment: If you put it in single quotes like that, then you will be assigning the literal string value `$info['google_id']` and not the value of that variable. Get rid of the outer pair of single quotes and it should work... again, assuming that $info['google_id'] actually contains a string or other valid data type.

Comment: Also, this seems like a perfectly good reason to define a constant using a variable. It's only a problem when you're not sure where the value will be coming from, or when you're using a variable because the value will be changing later.

Comment: @octern it is either a variable or a constant, it can't be both. If you are getting the value from an external source then it is a variable. What the OP wants to do is just plain wrong.

Comment: No, what the OP wants to do is entirely valid. Assigning a variable's value to a constant makes complete sense, in fact it's one of the fundamental ways to use it. You want to freeze the value you just retrieved from elsewhere, in your code, keeping it from being modified accidentally later.

Answer (score 8):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/define):

> The value of the constant; **only scalar and null values are allowed. Scalar values are integer, float, string or boolean values.** It is possible to define resource constants, however it is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior.

There is a possibility that the value you are retrieving from the database is not a string, but simply an object with a `__toString()` method.  To guarantee that the constant value is a string, try explicitly [casting the variable to string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
define('const_name', (string)$varible_name);
```

Comment: +1 - this is a common problem with people who are new to constants. Objects and Arrays cannot be stored in constants without serializing them first.

Comment: I can't believe I never realized I could store an array in a constant by serializing it. [cries]